# How to figure out what calls my php files

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, grep, cpanel

Before I describe the problem, here is a basic run-down of the overall process to give you a clearer picture. Additionally, I am a novice at PHP:

1. I have a WordPress website that uses CPanel as its web hosting software
2. The WordPress website has a form (made by UFB) that has the user upload an image
3. The image gets directed to the upload folder (/uploads) by using `image_upload.php`
4. The image is then downloaded onto a computer, and a program is run which generates numbers about the picture(the number generator program is in python)
5. After the numbers are generated, it calls on `report.php` and `template.xlsm`
6. Report.php gets those generated numbers and then puts them into their designated places on the xlsm file
7. The xlsm file is then converted into a pdf, which is then emailed to the user that submitted the picture.

I inherited all of this code from someone else who wanted me to help them on this project. Here is my problem:

*I don't understand how the PHP files are being called. I have python code ready to run the number generator online, however, I can't do this without figuring how the PHP files are being called.*

I understand what the PHP files do, I just don't understand how they are being called. I tried doing a `-grep` search for both `image_upload.php` and `report.php`, but I come up empty. There aren't any other PHP files that seem to do an `include(xyz.php)`, which is supposed to be how PHP files are called. I don't understand what calls `image_upload.php` to get the pictures moved into the /uploads folder. I also don't understand what calls `report.php` to make it run. I tried looking in `functions.php`, where most of the other PHP files are called, but `report.php` and `image_upload.php` aren't.

Please help me! If any clarification is needed, just comment, and I will try to provide any help I can!

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to get the the calling functions (including `include` and `require` calls) from any point in your PHP scripts is to get the stacktrace:

```
$e = new Exception();
var_dump($e->getTraceAsString());
```

You can also use an logger instead of the var_dump.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately a simple grep for requires and includes won't suffice for a large project like WordPress due to the use of autoloading:

https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php

While this resource isn't specific to your project, and things could be setup drastically different in your project, I think the details here may provide enough hints about autoloading to get you started in the right direction to understanding things in more depth:

https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/212153/using-spl-autoloading-within-wordpress-plugin